# Qt C++ How to save QByteArray for encrypted text to a file, then read and format back as a QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt, encryption, qbytearray

I have a very simple encrypt/decrypt program. After the encryption my program returns the encrypted text as a QByteArray which I then save into a text file. When retrieving the ByteArray from the file for decryption I'm not sure if it is formatting correctly or if the file is adding some kind of extra characters like a `\n`

Here is my encrypt/decrypt functions:

```
void Handler::updatePMEF(QString format) {

    SimpleCrypt crypto(Q_UINT64_C(0x0c2ad4a4acb9f023));
    QString result = crypto.encryptToByteArray(format);

    QFile file("C:/test.txt");
    if ( file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite) ) {
        QTextStream stream( &file );
        stream << result << endl;
    }
}

QString Handler::openPMEF() {
    QByteArray encrypted;

    QFile file("C:/test.txt");
    if ( file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly) ) {
         encrypted = file.readAll();
    }

    SimpleCrypt crypto(Q_UINT64_C(0x0c2ad4a4acb9f023));
    QString decrypted = crypto.decryptToByteArray(encrypted);

    return decrypted;
}
```

After calling `openPMEF()` the debugger returns nothing so I assume something is going wrong.

Before I tried doing `QByteArray = encrypted` in hopes that it would convert and the debugger returned:

```
Decrypyted: ????\u00153C?????qW\f????\u00153\u0019????\u00153\u001C????\u0006 \u001C?????2\u0014\u001C????\f*v?????\u00153'?????\u0004\"~?D?\u0005?\u00153(???? \u0006\u001Cf???\u00153I?????dB2??\u00153\u001C????\u00153l?????-\u000B\u001C?????\u00153I?????\u00153\u001C????\u0018>\u001Cf???\u00153(?????jLa????\u00153\u0006?????\u001D;)????DbK????~X\u0010Ö???\u0001'\u001B?????rTl?????\u0005#Z????X~Q?????F`G???²\u001A<B???? \u0006G?????F`r????? \u0006
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely because you used `QTextStream` upon writting. For instance, this one will most likely stop on the first OES (`\0`), while your crypted data may contain many.

You should use a function writting directly a `QByteArray`.

Try writting using this:

```
file.write( result.toAscii() );
```

I'm not sure what encoding you should use (that could also explain it fails in your code, if reading/writting enciding is different. You may try all available: `result.toLatin1()`, `result.toLocal8Bit()`, `result.toUtf8()`. Hopefully, one will work as expected.

By the way, maybe QString is not adapted to store your data in the first place. Can't you adapt `SimpleCrypt::encryptToByteArray` to return a `QByteArray`?

**Edit:** As discussed offline, final solution was to modify `SimpleCrypt::encryptToByteArray` to return a `QByteArray` instead of a `QString` (`QString` is meant to store strings not byte arrays)

Comment: I have converted it to UTF-8 upon writing, but then when reading it's returning null.

Comment: @JamieThirkell: See the edit in my post. Please first convert result to a `QByteArray` and check its size, to be sure you are writting something to the file!

Comment: @JamieThirkell: Could you tell us what did the trick in the end? Feel free to edit my post with final working code. This may help other people.